Azure container APP : how to nat for a network vitual appliance?
I'm new to Azure container application and networking.
I have an internal environment in a private VNET.
I use a virtual network appliance to publish my application ( ADC VPX CITRIX )
If I understand correctly :
If I query the url of the container app, it's the load balancer that is queried and it's one of the nodes that responds.
This means that the answering ip is different from the queried ip.
What should I do to ensure that it's the same ip in both cases?
Thanks
I've tried it with a small iis machine in the same vnet and it works perfectly.
But I can't get it to work with the container application.
My network appliance doesn't get a response from the loadbalancer and so it loops without displaying anything.
I can't find any Microsoft documentation for this case.
I can't active " floating ip " on the LB because i must delete my app env first
lb_rules
lb_error
I currently have case 1 and I want case 2
Case

what are you trying to achieve? Deploying to your container app from your private network ?

Yes exactly, we want a private env who must pass by our app gateway and firewall

deploying would be done through container registray and bicep. not sure to understand whats the issue ?

The problem isn't deploying but after
When i have created my env & app, a load balancer have been created but i can't modify it beceause it is in the subnet of my app
My app work fine, the long azure url  with the ip of the lb
My custom url work fine with the ip of the lb
but i need an virtual appliance to expose my app from outside my vnet
when my virtual appliance query the ip of the load balancer, the response don't come from the load balancer but from the node/app after the lb
So my virtual appliance think it don't get a response because it's not the same ip

Have you check the nat gateway integration? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking?tabs=workload-profiles-env%2Cazure-cli#nat-gateway-integration

that's what I was looking at but I'm having trouble applying it because of the existing load balancer/ container.
I'll redo an env and test
and for more clarity I've made a quick diagram that I've put above

I tried with a new env, the only solution microsoft proposes is to go through a gateway application, which forces me to take a public ip, I do not want a public ip.

app gateway is for inbound not outbound. i thought you were trying to get a fix ip for outbound?

that's correct. the nat gateway also require an public ip :
"When you configure a NAT Gateway on your subnet, the NAT Gateway provides a static public IP address for your environment. All outbound traffic from your container app is routed through the NAT Gateway's static public IP address. "

HO yeah sorry. you can configure UDR as well, maybe what you need? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking?tabs=workload-profiles-env%2Cazure-cli#user-defined-routes-udr

After a lot of research, it turns out that it's not possible to route traffic only internally, so we're obliged to route traffic via a public static ip (NAT GATEWAY). Afterwards, it's possible to install an Azure firewall to secure this traffic and do some nat on your side for this public static ip.
Thanks for your help anyway

if you use UDR you can route directly to azure firwall without a public ip: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking?tabs=workload-profiles-env%2Cazure-cli#user-defined-routes-udr


Azure container APP: how to Nat for a network virtual appliance

I agree with thomas that itss possible to route traffic directly to an Azure Firewall without using a public IP by utillizing User-Defined Routes (UDR).

Follow this steps
Azure-portal --> route-tables --> Define routes

Now make sure the route tables should be asssociate with the subnet when container app but for this to happen make sure the traffic from the subnet should be goes throught the azure firewall.
now create Azure firewall --> firewall rules such that it follows all  the outbound and inbound traffic from your Azure Container Apps.
Refer:
Networking in Azure Container Apps environment | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview
